# how do it get last 25 comments of facebook post with graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If there is post in facebook page with 100 comments..

In the first request I want to get the -last- 30 comments of the post..
and then use cursor/paging to get previous comments.

How can I get the -last- 30 comments ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did You Look Here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

Also, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/
it says there that a comment has a created_time field. You could get all the comments and then sort them in the app by date.

Comment: @Unicorn
I read. but I thought there is simple way to do it without messing and sorting the data on my side.

I mean, just grab the last page of comments and from there use the cursors to get previous pages or check for new comments

Comment: I think Alessandro Gabrielli might have answered your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your numbers:

```
SELECT text from comment where post_id={post_id} limit 30 offset 70
```